# Camel - NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue

Tags: apache-kafka, jackson, apache-camel

I am trying to move Json data in Kafka topic to Postgresql using camel-postgres-sink-connector in docker.

Here is the curl configuration:

```
curl -X POST \http://localhost:8083/connectors/ \-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "name": "<connector_name>",
    "config": {
    "connector.class": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.postgresqlsink.CamelPostgresqlsinkSinkConnector",
    "camel.kamelet.postgresql-sink.serverName": "localhost",
    "camel.kamelet.postgresql-sink.databaseName": "<server>",
    "topics": "<topic_name>",
    "camel.kamelet.postgresql-sink.password": "<db_pass>",
    "camel.kamelet.postgresql-sink.username": "<db_user>",
    "camel.kamelet.postgresql-sink.query": "insert into  public.employee_1(<schema>) values (:#col1,:#col2)",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "camel.kamelet.postgresql-sink.serverPort": "5432",
    "name": "<connector_name>,
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "driverClassName": "org.postgresql.Driver",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
}}'
```

Here is my docker yaml file configs:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
    container_name: broker
    ports:
    # To learn about configuring Kafka for access across networks see
    # https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
      - "29092:29092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  connectjdbc:
    container_name: connectjdbc
    image: debezium/connect-jdbc:1.0
    build:
      context: debezium-jdbc
    depends_on:
      - broker
    restart: always
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=broker:29092
      - GROUP_ID=1
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
```

I am receiving the below error while running initializing the connector:

Error message::

```
{
   "name":"<connector_name>",
   "connector":{
      "state":"RUNNING",
      "worker_id":"<ip>:8083"
   },
   "tasks":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "state":"FAILED",
         "worker_id":"<ip>:8083",
         "trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:561)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exchange delivery has failed!\n\tat org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSinkTask.put(CamelSinkTask.java:210)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:539)\n\t... 10 more\nCaused by: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[A9D1EDC81C97CCA-0000000000000000]\n\tat org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:45)\n\tat org.apache.camel.support.AbstractExchange.setException(AbstractExchange.java:597)\n\tat org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:27)\n\tat org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:94)\n\tat org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:477)\n\tat org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:61)\n\tat org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:182)\n\tat org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:399)\n\tat org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:96)\n\tat org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:214)\n\tat org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor$1.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)\n\tat org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:108)\n\tat org.apache.camel.support.cache.DefaultProducerCache.send(DefaultProducerCache.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:176)\n\tat org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:148)\n\tat org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSinkTask.put(CamelSinkTask.java:205)\n\t... 11 more\nCaused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.Class)'\n\tat org.apache.camel.component.jackson.AbstractJacksonDataFormat.unmarshal(AbstractJacksonDataFormat.java:184)\n\tat org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:76)\n\t... 25 more\n"
      }
   ],
   "type":"sink"
}
```

where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Why aren't you running camel connector as a container? Debezium doesn't come with Camel, last I checked

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am unable to find the camel image to connect with postgresql. Is there any reference which I could look into for image and configs? -Thanks

Comment: There is no Docker image. You will need to make your own and download Camel Connect JAR plugins into it